# How to repeat this for every line in rich text box?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, richtextbox

I am currently making myself a little tool.

Essentially I have this list which goes like this:

```
NPWR00160_00 LittleBigPlanet
NPWR00163_00 Warhawk
NPWR00179_00 Pure
NPWR00180_00 Midnight Club: Los Angeles
NPWR00181_00 echochrome™
NPWR00187_00 WipEout® HD
```

This is currently typed into a richTextBox.

I am trying to do this, get the NPWRXXXXXX of the line and save it as a string, and then the Games Name and save that as another string for which I can go ahead and do what I was originially going to do with it. But for each line of the richTextBox which carries on with that formation as above.

Not too sure how to get a line from the richTextBox and save it as a string, in which I can repeat that process for every single line of the richTextBox.

For what I have tried, I gave myself an example that the string was NPWR02727_00 Skydive: Proximity Flight. What I did was this:

```
    string game = "NPWR02727_00 Skydive: Proximity Flight";
    string NPWR = game.Substring(0,13);
    string gamename = game.Remove(0, 13);
    richTextBox2.AppendText("NPWRID: " + NPWR + " Game: " + gamename + Environment.NewLine);
```

Which actually does successfully save the strings and write it in the second text box as the new form.

Only issue is I'm not sure how to convert a line from the RichTextBox and turn it into a string, and repeat the process for each line in the rich text box

**EDIT**

So I found out how to turn a string into a line from the richTextBox..

`string line = richTextBox1.Lines[0];`

So this will get the first line and save it as the string "line"

This now updates the code to

```
string game = richTextBox1.Lines[0];
string NPWR = game.Substring(0,13);
string gamename = game.Remove(0, 13);
richTextBox2.AppendText("NPWRID: " + NPWR + " Game: " + gamename + Environment.NewLine);
```

Now how do I get this code to run for every line, I understand I need something to repeat it, and something to change the `0` to count up by 1 everytime it repeats?

**EDIT AGAIN**

Awesome, forget the above edit, thanks a lot!

Comment: `foreach (string s in richTextBox1.Lines) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do something similar to this:

```
        var codes = new List<string>();
        var games = new List<string>();

        foreach(var s in richTextBox1.Lines)
        {
            string[] p = s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);
            if (p.Count() == 1) { continue; }

            codes.Add(p[0]);
            games.Add(p[1]);
        }
```

Basically, we are declaring two Lists of the type *string*, to store respectively the code and the name of the game. Then we proceed in looping through the *Lines* property of the RichTextBox, and for each line, we split the line by the first index(*space*) we find; asking for a maximum of two strings, to avoid splitting any forthcoming elements; in case the name of the game contains spaces.

For the two substrings obtained, we proceed by saving the first part into the List codes, and the second one into the List games.

For further uses(traversing codes/names) we could access the two Lists

```
for(int c = 0; c < codes.Count; c++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(codes[c] + string.Empty + games[c]);
}
```